# How to increase the Google search results to display more than 100 results?

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I’m trying to save all the URLs of my website that are indexed in Google, so I want to increase the displayed search results to more than 100.

Is it possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is obsolete, and because the context give, the question belongs to [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct method to do this (as far as I know), but you can do this by simply Enabling Infinite Scroll on the results page, this is possible in multiple ways.

1. **(Only for Chrome)** Install [gInfinity](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ginfinity/dgomfdmdnjbnfhodggijhpbmkgfabcmn) form the Chrome Web Store, it will enable Infinite Scroll on Google Search results.
2. **(Only for Firefox)** Install [FastestFox](http://smarterfox.com/news/) for Firefox it will enable infinite google search results
3. **(Cross Browser)** There is a script available [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9310), its called [GoogleMonkeyR](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9310), You can install this script with extension like [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox and [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome. There would be more possible extensions for other browsers.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

go to [Preference Page Of Google](http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en)

and set results per page to what you want

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i wanted to display the search results listings more than 100 per page, is that possible?

Comment: @Arun if you register your web apps account with the same OpenID you used on Super User you'll regain ownership of the question.